# How to create a crosstab programatically with Telerik Reporting?

Tags: telerik, reporting, crosstab, telerik-reporting

I am working with the telerik reporting platform. I am trying to create a crosstab programatically and I cant seem to find any documentation on this particular subject. I have created a forum post [Crosstab Documenation Question](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/crosstab-documentation.aspx) but I'm not counting on telerik to do anything helpful.

If anyone has a link or code sample i could reference that would be great.

Comment: Can you create a CrossTab using the designer?  If so create a few examples along the lines of those you want to create programmatically and then look at the backing code - it's all code driven.

Comment: I can reverse engineer this process I suppose, however that is rather time consuming and error prone without a solid foundation of what is required and why.

Comment: I agree it'll probably use up a day - but I don't think you'll find great docs on this - and reverse engineering it will give you a proper understanding.  Just looking at some report backing code now - it's not particularly complicated - just very repetitive.

Comment: very true. Move this to an answer and ill mark it as such.

Comment: Thank you very much - I didn't think it really merited an answer as it's not a huge amount of help.  Good luck with the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you create CrossTabs using the designer.  Create a few examples along the lines of those you want to create programmatically and then look at the backing code - it's all code driven.